# exchange of information between 2 applications android without databases

Tags: android

**good afternoon**, how could I make 2 applications send and receive data between them without using database or services?

I have an application "A" and has implemented functions that query to a device that is connected to the smartphone, which is a way for an application "B" to communicate with "A" and to exchange information?

I can not use databases because the information must not be stored on any site security

Comment: You can do it by implementing public shared preferences that both apps access

Comment: If you don't want to store data, then shared preferences is no good to you either. Have you looked at custom Intents with signature permissions?

Comment: I'd use aidl with a service.